# Is there a way to support nested grouping in material ui's Autocomplete component?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Have been trying to implement nested grouping in material ui's Autocomplete component, but can't seem to figure out how to implement it.
The intention is for a person to be listed under a department, which again can be listed under a "parent department", potentially unlimited times, so some recursion is necessary
But I feel in over my head, and can't get the grouping right.

Here's how far I've gotten:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/core/Autocomplete';
import { ListSubheader, ListHeader } from '@material-ui/core';
function DropdownField (props) {
    const {id, label, options, defaultValue, variant} = props;
    var {helperText} = props;
    
    
    // If defaultValue is set, manipulate newOptions array by moving the defaultValue item to the top (newOptions[0])
    if (defaultValue) {
        let index = options.findIndex((item) => item.id == defaultValue);
        if (index !== -1) {
            newOptions = [options[index], ...options.filter(item => item !== options[index])];
            // let tempItem = {...options[index]};
            // tempItem.label = '- '+tempItem.label;
            // options.unshift(tempItem);
        } else {
            newOptions = [options[defaultValue], ...options.filter(function (item, index) { return item != options[index]})];
        }
    }
    const createGroups = (options) => {
        let groups = {};
        options.map(option => {
            if (option.groupBy) {
                if (groups[option.groupBy.id]) {
                    option.groupBy = groups[option.groupBy.id];
                } else {
                    groups[option.groupBy.id] = {label:option.groupBy.label, id: option.groupBy.id};
                    option.groupBy = groups[option.groupBy.id];
                }
            }
            else {
                option.groupBy = null;
            }
        });
        return groups;
    }
    const handledGroups = createGroups(options);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(props.disabled || false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState((newOptions && newOptions[0]) || options[0] || null);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState((options[0] && options[0].label) || "");

    const onChangeHandler = (event, newValue) => {
        props.onAccept(event, newValue || {id: null, label: null});
        setValue(newValue);
    }

    const handleDisable = (disabled = true) => {
        return setDisabled(disabled);
    }

    const valueChangeHandler = (valueID) => {
        let index = options.findIndex((item) => item.id == valueID);
        if (index !== -1) {
            setValue(options[index]);
            setInputValue(options[index].label);
        } else if (options[valueID] !== undefined) {
            setValue(options[valueID]);
            setInputValue((options[valueID] && options[valueID].label) || options[valueID] || null);
        } else {
            console.warn('Invalid id:', );
        }
    }

    const renderGroup = (params) => {
        let groupHeaders = [];
        if (params.group && params.group.id && handledGroups[params.group.id].parentGroup) {
            groupHeaders.push(<ListHeader key={params.key} component="div">{handledGroups[handledGroups[params.group.id].parentGroup].label}</ListHeader>)
        }
        groupHeaders.push(<ListSubheader key={100+params.key} component="div">{params.group && params.group.id ? handledGroups[params.group.id].label :"Ungrouped"}</ListSubheader>);
        groupHeaders.push(params.children);
        return groupHeaders;
    };


    return (
        <Autocomplete
            value={value}
            onChange={onChangeHandler}
            inputValue={inputValue}
            onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                setInputValue(newInputValue);
            }}
            disablePortal
            groupBy={option => {
                console.log(option.groupBy);
                return option.groupBy && option.groupBy.id ? handledGroups[option.groupBy.id] : null}}
            getOptionDisabled={item => item.disabled}
            disabled={disabled}
            renderGroup={renderGroup}
            id={id}
            options={options}
            sx={{width:300}}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} variant={variant || "standard"} />}
        />
    );
}

export default DropdownField;
```

Comment: Am btw aware that ListHeader isn't a component in Material-UI x) Using next.material-ui, and React 17

Comment: can u provide data input?

Comment: Hey! @RainerKildal Did you remember how did you solve that issue?